# Java 3D Plot Library

Tags: library, java, 3d

I need a Java library for a 3D coordinate system in which I can do linear programming. Functions, planes, arrows and points should be drawn and colored. Points should be able to be labeled. There should be a zoom function and a rotation function. I tried to integrate Jzy3D into IntelliJ, neither the demo nor the Marvelrepositories could be integrated. Does anyone know any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use DataMelt Java program. You can see samples of the outputs here: https://jwork.org/dmelt/code/index.php?art=Plots/3D

The nice thing about these 3D plots (functions, data) are interactive, and can be saved to the vector graphics